# How to disable double-click-to-edit-mode in IBM Notes?

Tags: lotus-notes

Should be a simple one - I'm using IBM Notes (aka Lotus Notes) as an email client. I'm one of those people who click around while they read documents - take away my left mouse button and I'd be illiterate. Unfortunately, in Notes this habit causes an email to go into edit mode, making things jump around, which is obviously very uncomfortable and happens in no other application I've ever seen.

Is there a way to disable the double-click-to-edit-mode functionality? I've searched Google but only turned up some sort of action script. I'm free to tinker with config files if there's an option there.

OS: Windows 10

Comment: I don't think there's a setting for that, but in any case this question belongs on SuperUser, not on StackOverflow.

Comment: It kind of is a Stackoverflow question, but only if he has a Domino Designer. But as a normal user the answer is: Not possible...

Comment: Apologies, Richard is quite right. I should have asked on SU. Is it possible to move it? Not that it makes a difference if there's no solution...